# How to make a HDMI signal be identified as HDMI instead of DVI?

Tags: fpga, video, hdmi

I am experimenting with the HDMI port of an [ULX3S](https://radiona.org/ulx3s/) FPGA board. I have been able to properly generate DVI signals with a resolution of 800x600 and framerate of 60 Hz. I am now trying generate actual HDMI signals (instead of DVI). I order to do so, I have modified the design to include the extra signalization required by HDMI. Before each row of pixel data, I am including the 8-pixel video preamble (as described in the HDMI 1.4b standard, section 5.2.1.1) and the 2-pixel video guard (as described in section 5.2.2).

The screen, instead of identifying the signal as HDMI, it still identifies it as DVI, with a resolution of 802x600, and shows a 2-pixel magenta column at the left of the image, so it seems that it is treating the 2-pixel guard as pixel data.

According to annex C.3,

> An HDMI Sink, upon power-up, reset or detection of a new source device, shall assume that the source device is limited to the above behavior. Upon the detection of an indication that the source is HDMI-capable, the HDMI Sink shall follow all of the HDMI Sink-related requirements specified in this document.

I am not sure what a "an indication that the source is HDMI-capable" is. Is the inclusion of the video preamble and guards enough or is there anything else needed to have the sink identify the signal as HDMI instead of DVI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the guard bands are not enough. There needs to be data islands sent too. Maybe null packets are enough, but general control packets should be sent almost every frame.

And since the signal is detected as 802 active pixels, there could be something wrong with the guard band transmission.